# How to change the label property of a QTabWidget on double click?

Tags: qt, kde-plasma, qtabwidget

How do I recognize a double click on a tab in order to change its label?
Preferrably I could edit the label in place but alternatively I could also get a string from another input box. Any suggestions?
The tab gets added and the label specified currently like:

```
QString tab_label = QString("Shell (") + QString::number(session->id(), 16) + ")";
    addTab(session->widget(), tab_label);
```

and I'd want to be able to edit the label after creation.

Oh and I should mention here that I'm a Qt newbie, too!

**EDIT1**
full method:

```
int SessionStack::addSession(Session::SessionType type)
{
    Session* session = new Session(type, this);
    connect(session, SIGNAL(titleChanged(int,QString)), this, SIGNAL(titleChanged(int,QString)));
    connect(session, SIGNAL(terminalManuallyActivated(Terminal*)), this, SLOT(handleManualTerminalActivation(Terminal*)));
    connect(session, SIGNAL(activityDetected(Terminal*)), m_window, SLOT(handleTerminalActivity(Terminal*)));
    connect(session, SIGNAL(silenceDetected(Terminal*)), m_window, SLOT(handleTerminalSilence(Terminal*)));
    connect(session, SIGNAL(destroyed(int)), this, SLOT(cleanup(int)));

    m_sessions.insert(session->id(), session);

    QString tab_label = QString("Shell (") + QString::number(session->id(), 16) + ")";
    addTab(session->widget(), tab_label);

    emit sessionAdded(session->id());

    raiseSession(session->id());

    return session->id();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a QTabBar::tabBarDoubleClicked signal, you just need to connect it to a slot to detect a double click. Also you'll need some widget to actually edit the tab's text. If you want it "out of place" (say, you open a dialog) then it should be enough to do something like:

```
connect(tabWidget->tabBar(), &QTabBar::tabBarDoubleClicked,
        this, MyWidget::editTabBarLabel);

void MyWidget::editTabBarLabel(int tabIndex)
{
    if (tabIndex < 0)
        return;
    // open dialog asking for the new label,
    // f.i. via QInputDialog::getText

    // set the new label bakc
}
```

If instead you want some in-place modification you'll need to more or less heavily modify QTabBar to do so.

The simplest option would be opening a QLineEdit on the right tab. To get the geometry of a tab via QTabBar:.tabrect, so that you can place the line edit in the same geometry. You'll very likely fall short on that path (see below) and you'll need to subclass QTabBar and use `initStyleOption` for the given tab, then set the lineedit's geometry to the right subrect (for instance, do not cover the "side widgets" of a tab).

Random pseudo braindumped code:

```
void MyTabBar::editTabBarLabel(int tabIndex)
{
    if (tabIndex < 0)
        return;

    if (!m_lineEdit) {
        m_lineEdit = new QLineEdit(this);
        // once done, commit the change, or abort it, anyhow
        // destroy/hide (?) the line edit
        connect(m_lineEdit, &QLineEdit::editingFinished,
                this, &MyTabBar::renameLabel);
    } else {
        // we're actually editing something else, what to do?
        // commit the other change and start editing here?
    }

    m_editedTabIndex = tabIndex; // remember which one we're editing
    m_lineEdit->setText(tabText(tabIndex));     

    // not "entirely" accurate, you need better subrect control here,
    // cf. QStyle and https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/style-reference.html#widget-walkthrough
    // that's why this should really be a QTabBar subclass, because
    // you'll need to invoke initStyleOption and then fetch the subrects from the style

    m_lineEdit->setGeometry(tabRect(tabIndex));
    m_lineEdit->show();
}

// also track resize of the tabbar, relayout, tab reorder, tab insertion and removal, etc.
// move the QLineEdit accordingly
```

Comment: Hi, I'm wondering what `tabWidget->` is (in `connect()`)..? I've added the code from the method that adds the session and the tab into my original post under **EDIT1**

Comment: It's the QTabWidget you have around.